# (intermediate value).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am reasonable new to Javascript.
Currently I am converting some ES6 code back to ES5 code, because of some legacy systems. 
I converted the following code:

```
$row.find('.gridCellDetailAction')
 .each((i, elem) => $translate('Grid.Show' + $(elem).attr('data-title') + 's')
.then(trans => $(elem).attr('title', trans)));
```

To this

```
   $row.find('.gridCellDetailAction')
        .each(function (i, elem) {
              $translate('Grid.Show' + $(elem).attr('data-title') + 's')
   }.then(function (trans) { $(elem).attr('title', trans) }));
```

Now I am getting the following error:

> (intermediate value).then is not a function

Now I know that I do something wrong with the `then`. But how can I get the same result?

Comment: can babel help ?

Comment: I can see a close bracket `}` in wrong place, the one before `.then`. That one should be placed just before the last `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of formatting you can easily see the difference.
One time you are calling `then` on the result of `$translate` and the other time you are calling `then` on a function definiton.

```
$row.find('.gridCellDetailAction')
.each(
  (i, elem) => {
    $translate(
     'Grid.Show' + $(elem).attr('data-title') + 's'
    )
    .then(
      trans => $(elem).attr('title', trans)
    )
  }
);
```

```
$row.find('.gridCellDetailAction')
.each(
  function (i, elem) {
    $translate('Grid.Show' + $(elem).attr('data-title') + 's')
  }// <-- The error is here
  .then(
    function (trans) { 
      $(elem).attr('title', trans) 
    }
  )
);
```

This would be correct:

```
$row.find('.gridCellDetailAction')
.each(
  function (i, elem) {
    $translate('Grid.Show' + $(elem).attr('data-title') + 's')
    .then(  //Now then is called on the result of $translate
      function (trans) { 
        $(elem).attr('title', trans) 
      }
    )
  }
);
```

Comment: Great that I was able to help you. You should mark this answer as correct so that other users can find it easily

Answer (score 0):

**What is Wrong:**
From your code, I will remove `$row.find('.gridCellDetailAction').each();`

```
function (i, elem) {
    $translate('Grid.Show' + $(elem).attr('data-title') + 's')
}
.then(function (trans) { $(elem).attr('title', trans) })
```

This code seems wrong;
So, We need put `.then(function (trans) { $(elem).attr('title', trans) })` in the `function()`

---

**Complete code:**

```
$row.find('.gridCellDetailAction')
    .each(function (i, elem) {
        $translate('Grid.Show' + $(elem).attr('data-title') + 's')
            .then(function (trans) { $(elem).attr('title', trans) });
    });
```

Comment: This is not very helpful. You should try to explain why his/her code does not work and what you did differently than him/her